# Is it possible to change the email file attachment name in Oracle APEX Interactive Report Subscription?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to change the default template in Oracle APEX Interactive Report-> Subscription -> Email Attachment ? , I'd like to have the attachment with the Report name instead of it being called Report.html